# I can't really understand the first half of this author's argument

Tags: ring-theory, modules, proof-explanation

http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2009;task=show_msg;msg=1954.0001

I am specifically referring to this part

> Lets prove first that it is not left Artinian. Let $b_1,b_2,\dots$ be a
>   Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ (the reals) as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ (the rationals)
>   To make my life easier denote by $[a~ b]$ the matrix with $a,b$ in the
>   first row and zeros in the second. Then the following sequence of
>   ideals never stabilizes. $([1 ~b_1])$ includes $([1~ b_1],[1 ~b_1+b_2])$
>   includes $([1~ b_1],[1 ~b_1+b_2],[1, ~b_1+b_2+b_3])$ includes ...Check
>   that. Essentially is because you can not get $b_n$ as a linear
>   combination of $b_1,b_2,...b_{n-1}$ over the rationals since they are a
>   basis.

I do not understand what the author is saying. But I understand the second half just fine. More specifically, what does it mean for the sequence (where the matrices are specifically elements of this matrix ring).

$\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\b_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right) \subseteq\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\b_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\b_1 + b_2 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right) \subseteq\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\b_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\b_1 + b_2 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\b_1 + b_2 + b_3 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)$
to never stabilize.

Comment: What part don't you understand about this ?

Comment: I don't see how the sequence of ideals never stabilizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To stabilize" means that the ideal end up being in an ideal that generates the entire ring. That is how the author is using the word. The sequence of ideals never stabilizes because each of the elements in the Hamel basis is orthogonal from the rest of elements and subsequently cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the rest of the elements.